# How would you import a JSON file into JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON file with content

```
{"name" : "Conrad", "info" : "tst", "children" : [
    {"name" : "Rick" },
    {"name" : "Lynn" },
    {"name" : "John", "children": [
        {"name" : "Dave", "children": [
            {"name" : "Dave" },
            {"name" : "Chris" }      
        ]},
        {"name" : "Chris" }
    ]}
  ]};
```

I want to import this JSON file data inside a JavaScript file and have the final result like

```
var treeData ={"name" : "Conrad", "info" : "tst", "children" : [
        {"name" : "Rick" },
        {"name" : "Lynn" },
        {"name" : "John", "children": [
                {"name" : "Dave", "children": [
                {"name" : "Dave" },
                {"name" : "Chris" }

         ] },
                {"name" : "Chris" }
         ]}
  ]};
```

I've tried many code samples but none have worked.

Answer (score 12):

Parse the content of the file like this:

```
var treeData = JSON.parse(fileContent);
```

You don't describe how you obtain the file but you can load it off of your server using a simple XMLHttpRequest. Here is a useful resource for that: 
[Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Excerpt from the link with modifications:

```
var treeData;

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", "yourFile.txt", true);
oReq.send();

function reqListener(e) {
    treeData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
}
```

**Update** based on comments below:

You cannot *load* a file with `JSON.parse()`. This function is only able to convert an existing string into an object (if content is in valid JSON format).

You need to:

1. Load the file from your server to a variable using for example AJAX (as shown). You cannot use a local file path due to security reasons. Set up a local server to run your page in such as the free light-weight [Mongoose web server](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/). This will let you point the root to your local folder, then load your page using `http://localhost/`
2. When file has been loaded you can pass the content to the `JSON.parse()` function. The example above show the whole process. Just replace links with actual ones in your code.

(PS: if you wanted a jQuery solution remember to tag your question with the jQuery tag)

Comment: var treeData = JSON.parse('C:\Users\Bubee\Desktop\Paser Tree\codepen_DjKIa\test.json');

it doesn't work

Comment: @user3248233 you can't use a local file, it has to be on your server (security related). You can set up a simple local server to test such as f.ex. [Mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/). That allows you to use http links which you need here (ie. `http://localhost/.../test.json`, replace with an actual link). Also, you can't *load* a file with JSON.parse. You need to load the file using the ajax call as shown in the answer, then pass the result to JSON.parse. Hope this helps.-

Comment: In some cases, it is also useful to set the type of the file, for example `oReq.overrideMimeType("text/plain");` If you don't do this, than sometimes will occur `not well-formed` error.

Answer (score 9):

How about `$.getJSON`

```
$.getJSON( "yourjsonfile.json", function( data ) {  
    console.log( "JSON Data: " + data);
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        console.log(key + "value:: " + val );
    });
});
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: It works well, just a note : as with K3N answer you will have to have a local server to run this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Do an AJAX request of your JSON file, then use JSON.parse to add the result into treeData.

```
var treeData = JSON.parse(ajaxFunction('jsonfile.php'));
```

Something to that effect... (it will vary depending on your AJAX function)

Answer (score 0):

If someone is using GULP then here is how you can solve:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    insert = require('gulp-insert');

gulp.task('jsonConcat', function() {
  return gulp.src(['path/to/json/your-file.json'])
    .pipe(insert.prepend('treeData = '))
    .pipe(insert.append(';'))
    .pipe(concat('final-result.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/destination/'));
});
```