# How to import Mongoose to use json.parse()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, mongoose-web-server

I really want to use this code to import json file to javascript

```
var treeData;
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", "test.json", true);
oReq.send();
function reqListener(e) {
    treeData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
}
```

But i can't use JSON.parse for some reason

Someone told me I have to import [Mongoose web server](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) too set my local folder in javascript

please teach me how to import it thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing but JSON.parse is part of ECMAscript 5 and most browsers support it natively. @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450227/import-json-file-to-javascript   soneone advice me to import it

Comment: Mongoose http://mongoosejs.com/ or mongoose https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/?

Comment: Why is your `treeData` a global variable - the value is only available inside `reqListener`?

Comment: @user3248233: That's completely unrelated from `JSON.parse`. He's telling you that `XMLHttpRequest` cannot load files from your disk for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you can import jquery, you can do $.parseJSON(this.responseText);